# how to merge new zipped list into the middle of existing zipped list using python

Tags: python, list, loops, zip

I got this original list:

```
list1=[['jennifer ryann', 'jennifer lopez'],[' jennifer anniston', 'jennifer jason leigh and jennifer morrison', 'Jennifer Garner']]
```

due to some reasons, i split the sublist:

```
from itertools import chain
lists = list(chain.from_iterable(list1))
```

I also need to zip the elements:

```
list2 = [(el1, el2) for el1, el2 in zip(lists, lists[1:])]
```

All items in list2 are in pairs(zipped list) for instance,('jennifer ryann', 'jennifer lopez').Few pairs items containing '**and**' word such as (' jennifer anniston', 'jennifer jason leigh and jennifer morrison').

I'm going to do :

1. If the **'and'** word found in the element, the elements will be
   split and the word '**and**' should be removed. For example,the word
   '**and**' containing in the element **'jennifer jason leigh' and '
   jennifer morrison'** will be removed.
2. Then, the pair element  ' **jennifer anniston**' will be zipped
   with the both splitted elements  **'jennifer jason leigh'** and **'
   jennifer morrison'**.  It will generate two new zipped items such as 
   (' jennifer anniston', 'jennifer jason leigh') 
   and (' jennifer anniston', 'jennifer morrison')
3. And also, the both splitted elements 
   '**jennifer jason leigh**' and ' **jennifer morrison**' will be
    zipped with the next element  **'Jennifer Garner'**. These could be generated two more zipped elements ('jennifer jason leigh','Jennifer Garner') and ('jennifer morrison','Jennifer Garner')

The expected output would be like this:

```
[('jennifer ryann', 'jennifer lopez'), ('jennifer lopez', ' jennifer anniston'), (' jennifer anniston', 'jennifer jason leigh '),(' jennifer anniston', ' jennifer morrison'), (' jennifer jason leigh ', 'jennifer Garner ') , (' jennifer morrison ', 'jennifer Garner ') ]
```

In my code, i'm able to generate the new zipped list in the current zipped list, but i'm not able to combine the current zipped list into the list2.

This is my code

```
curr_zipp = []

for s, sublists in enumerate(list2):
    for e in range(len(sublists)):
        if 'and' in sublists[e]:
            if e== 1 :
                root_elem = sublists[e - 1]
                split_elem = sublists[e].split('and')
                curr_zipp.append((root_elem,split_elem[0]))
                curr_zipp.append((root_elem,split_elem[1]))


            elif e ==0:
                root_elem = sublists[e -1]
                split_elem = sublists[e].split('and')
                curr_zipp.append((split_elem[0],root_elem))
                curr_zipp.append((split_elem[1],root_elem))
```

I hope somebody can help me to merge the curr_zip list without changing the current position of the items. Maintaining the position number is important for me
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`list2[:2]+curr_zipp` will give you your required list.